# Looping through textbox contorls in vb.net to push data into a table

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple loop I am trying to use to capture data from a form and put it in to a stored procedure that updates a table.  It seems to me like it should do what it's supposed to do, but I'm getting a conversion error and I'm not really sure why.  I don't even know if it does in fact work since I'm getting an error that doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  Here's what I have currently:

```
    Dim rowcounter As Integer = 1

    While rowcounter < 15
        Dim NameHolder As String = "LineID" + rowcounter.ToString
        CMD.CommandTimeout = 60
        CMD.Connection = CONN
        CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        CMD.CommandText = "UpdateArchived"
        CMD.Parameters.Clear()
        CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Me.Controls(NameHolder).ToString)
        DA.SelectCommand = CMD
        DS.Clear()
        DA.Fill(DS)
    End While
```

The error is with the Me.Controls(NameHolder).ToString line.  It says the following: Conversion from string "LineID1" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

What is being converted to an integer here?  Does Me.Control return the control as an integer?

Comment: what type of control is `LineID1`?

Comment: I tried that but it gives me the error - "Text is not a member of System.Web.UI.Control."  LineID1 - LineID14 are textboxes.

Comment: My guess - the @ID parameter of the stored procedure is defined as an integer.

Comment: I tried a Ctype before in a slightly different way and it didn't work. I tried this and it produced the same error.  Even when I just try to put it in a msgbox to display.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loop over all textboxes in a form, including those inside a groupbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673950/loop-over-all-textboxes-in-a-form-including-those-inside-a-groupbox)

Comment: I also thought that it was the parameter, but I changed it in the stored procedure and it even throws the error when I don't assign it to that paramter.

Comment: Guys... Me.Controls() expects an integer, hence the error. Look at the link above to see how to loop through and find controls. You'll need a recursive function. Another useful post, though in C# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336839/asp-net-findcontrol-and-gridview-returning-null/13337066#13337066

Comment: I must have misinterpreted the use of Me.Controls in the examples I looked at then.

Comment: Unrelated - when will that loop end?

Comment: Never, because I somehow lost the counter in all those edits.

Answer (score 1):

Try using & not +

Both are concat operators but + will try and add an integer to an integer, hence the error. & only deals with strings.

So..

```
Dim NameHolder As String = "LineID" & rowcounter.ToString
```

HTH

Comment: also, I assume "option strict" is off in your case, if so it would wise to turn this on and this exception would be flagged before building the code.

Comment: I tried it but the error was the same.  The strange thing is that if I output NameHolder in a msgbox it displays LineID1, but for some reason when I try to access that control it gives me that same error. Like somehow "LineID1" is an integer.