# Null Reference Exception when attempting to bind dropdownlist inside formview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms, nullreferenceexception

I have an edit button and a dropdownlist inside a formview. I am using Linq To Entities to get the data I need to work with and have no problem populating and viewing the formview itemtemplate.

However, the dropdownlist control (`id="ddlEligibility"`) is only in the`edititemtemplate` (I use a textbox in the `itemtemplate` to display the current value) and I am having a problem binding this control to the datasource.

Specifically, when I click the Edit button I am getting a `NullReferenceException - "Object not set to an instance of an object"` on the last line of code below.  Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fvSubscriber.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
    fvSubscriber.DataBind(); // Adding this line solved the first problem where I could not find the control

    LifeLineDSEntities context = new LifeLineDSEntities():

    var program = from p in context.EligibilityPrograms
                  select p;

    DropDownList ddlEligibility = (DropDownList)(fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlEligibility")));

    if (ddlEligibility != null)
    {
        ddlEligibility.DataSource = program;
        ddlEligibility.DataTextField = "ProgramName";
        ddlEligibility.DataValueField = "eligibilityCode";
        ddlEligibility.DataBind();
        statusMessage.InnerHtml = "It is NOT null";
    }
    else
    {
        statusMessage.InnerHtml = "It is null";
    }
}
```

DropDownlist in FormView...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:FormView ID="fvSubscriber" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="false" DefaultMode="Readonly" OnModeChanging="fvSubscriberChanging">
        <ItemTemplate>
           // mark up here
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEligibility" runat="server" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</form>
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried the FindControlRecursive method discussed in the accepted answer in the link below (for FormView though) to see if for some reason the control was not where I thought it was but still no luck, it always comes back null.  When I view source on the page, the control "ddlEligibility" is there.

[ASP.net .FindControl() and GridView returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336839/asp-net-findcontrol-and-gridview-returning-null)

**New Update**
I was able to find the control by adding fvSubsriber.databind() as shown in the code above, however I am unable to get the edititemtemplate to show the value in the dropdownlist that was displayed in the itemtemplate.  In the edititemtemplate is just default to the first item in dropdownlist.  I have added the code above.  I have moved this new problem to a new post

Comment: Most likely, it cannot find the control ddlEligibility. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: Have you tried putting ddlEligibility into a variable of type DropDownList to make sure it can be found?  That'd be my most likely guess as to the problem

Comment: What is fvSubscriber? It's not passed into the method.

Comment: @Christopher Stevenson fvSubscriber isn't null, or he would have got an error on the third line calling fvSubscriber.ChangeMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, peform a check before giving a datasource

```
var ddlEligibility = ((DropDownList)(fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlEligibility")));

if(ddlEligibility!=null)
{
   ddlEligibility.DataSource = program;
   ddlEligibility.DataBind();
} 
else
{
   statusMesage.InnerHtml = "IT IS NULL";
}
```

Comment: Actually that kind of cast throws an exception. You would need `var ddlEligibility = (fvSubscriber.FindControl("ddlEligibility")) as DropDownList;` to get a null value.

Comment: Hello meda, Thanks for your help.  I am not getting the null exception now, however my dropdownlist is empty.

Comment: @Jason you have to bind the dropdown to the datasource after assinging it, see my update

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson the exception is thrown when you attempt to access the control but is null this is why I added the condition

Comment: @meda If this object you're casting is not in fact a DropDownList, you would get a CastException. As an implementer, you need to decide if that exception is an error to fix, or an error to ignore.

Comment: @meda, I added the else statement to my code and am getting the message so apparently ddlEligibility is null.

Comment: @Jason how did you create `ddlEligibility` show it in your post

Comment: @meda I added the markup to my post that creates ddlEligibility